# my updates will not connect

Tags: 12.04, 14.04

It gives me this

```
E:Malformed line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
E:The list of sources could not be read.
E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error at line 3 of your /etc/apt/sources.list file.
Fix it manually by running

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

or post contents of this file to your question, if you need help.